# How to make those 2 commands work together in one bash line?

Tags: bash, tftp

I would like to connect via tftp with: `tftp Server_IP Port`

THEN to get a file from the server with: `get filename.txt`

The server I'm trying to connect to in FreeBSD, here is doc about the FreeBSD tftp client [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tftp&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE)

I want to make those two commands in one Bash line, I was thinking of `tftp Server_IP Port; get filename.txt` but it does not work.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `tftp Server_IP Port GET filename.txt` ? It would work with [this windows client](http://www.tftp-server.com/tftp-client.html), no idea about yours.

Comment: `get filename.txt` is *not* a `bash` command; it is a command sent to the FTP server by `tftp`.

Comment: @Aaron No it does not work, the server is Linux

Comment: Looks like the client's syntax for passing a command is `tftp Server_IP Port -c GET filename.txt`. I think this should fix your problem, I'll post it as a solution.

Comment: @Aaron I just tried, it does not work

Comment: Hmm, can you report anything about your `tftp` client version? I was using [this manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tftp), according to which the `-c` syntax should work.

Comment: @Aaron I'm trying to, but it doesn't give much interesting stuffs

Comment: @Aaron Isn't there another way by backgrounding the bash session ?

Comment: You may bet able to pass commands to the `tftp` process through its standard input ; have you tried the pipe solution I commented on my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on its implementation, your `tftp` client might have an option to accept a command as a parameter instead of opening an interactive session.

If it isn't the case, it should at least accept input from its standard input (`stdin`). You can send data through this stream by piping a previous command, for example a simple `echo` :

```
echo "GET filename.txt" | tftp Server_IP Port
```

The `tftp` client might detect it receives data from a pipe and avoid launching an interactive tftp shell ; if it's not the case, just add `;quit` at the end of your command in order to exit the FTP session and thus the `tftp` process.

Comment: sorry I just updated my post, I can't accept your answer

Comment: No problem, thanks for adding your client's manpage. Can you try `echo "GET filename.txt" | tftp Server_IP Port` ? Add a `;quit` at the end of the echoed string if it works but leaves you with the ftp prompt.

Comment: Sorry I was oon something else, I'm trying now

Comment: Your comment works !! (with the pipe)

Comment: I wait that you update your answer

Comment: Done. Did you have to use a `;quit` or did the `tftp` client run non-interactively?